# Acceptability of Kundalini Shakti and Chakras across Hinduism?

Tags: vedanta, yoga, moksha, chakras, kundalini

How well is the concept of *Kundalini Shakti*, the body *Chakras*, the *nāḍīs* and subsequently their role in the attainment of *Mokṣa* (in its various types and levels of hierarchies across different belief systems), is accepted or prevalent across various sects/*sampradāyas* and/or  Schools of Thoughts, under the *āstika* system?

What about the major schools of vedanta - *Bhedabheda, Dvaita, Viśiṣṭādvaita, Advaita, & Suddhadvaita*? What has been their views on it, historically and presently, vis-a-vis their major philosophers and *acharyas*?

How well does the concept of *Mokṣa*, and its dependence on *Kundalini & Chakras* to achieve it, gels with the three (or four) paths of *yoga* - i.e., *Karma yoga, Bhakti yoga, Jñan yoga, & Rãja yoga*?

Which of the above paths and belief systems, even identify with or accept *Kundalini*, as a major or minor principle (although not necessarily in connection with *Mokṣa*) ?